# Generating a p2 repository from a local folder, so that it can be used in a target platform

Tags: eclipse-rcp, tycho, eclipse-pde, p2, target-platform

I want to build an RCP application with Maven and Tycho. For this I need to change my target platform which is only a folder in the file-system to a p2 repository.
To generate the p2 repository I created a new workspace, set the target platform and followed [this tutorial](http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/provisioning-your-target-platform-as-local-p2-site/).

Eclipse generates a p2 repository for me and all seems fine, but when I want to set this generated p2 repository as target platform in Eclipse it fails. Eclipse says that `org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.finder` requires the package `javax.swing.text`.
I searched a bit and found out that `javax.swing.text` is a part from the JDK, and some people somehow managed to get the JDK into the p2 repository.

How can I to satisfy this dependency and make the target resolution pass?

Comment: It seems that people have answered your original question. If you edit it and add a follow-up question to it, this makes the existing answers incomplete or even wrong. Therefore it is discouraged to significantly change questions after they've been answered. Instead, you should ask a new question for your follow-up problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is an effect of the JDK itself not being an OSGi bundle.
The eclipse release train repositories have a fake "a.jre.javase" installable unit which provide all the packages in the JDK to work around this problem.

Try adding http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo to the p2 repositories of your build.

Also se related bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364095

Comment: I put the <unit id='a.jre.javase' version='1.6.0' singleton='false'> ...<\unit> in the content.xml from the content.jar -> It works   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Threre's a "special" IU that represents the packages provided by the
JDK. There's whole discussion about generating *a.jre.javase*  **IU**  at Eclipse Community Forums: [[p2] how to generate "a.jre.javase" IU?](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/159026/). [Here's](https://github.com/jarek-przygodzki/p2-metadata-publisher)  p2 metadata publisher creating  JRE IU based on **Phil Denis** sample. Alternatively, IU can be created by [this](https://gist.github.com/jarek-przygodzki/c61430c42a045f3c87d0) p2 advice file (*p2.inf*).